# Fastest way to add/remove multiple elements in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

**Edit: It's not a duplicate of "Fastest DOM insertion" because it includes the event listeners variable too. Anyway I will edit the question.**

I would to know some things if someone already discovered.

I would like to know which is the fastest way to add an element in javascript and to be compatible with ie6+, chrome10+, firefox2+.

Fastest technique to:

1. Add a single element
2. Add 100 elements
3. Any time curve for adding 1 element or 1000 elements
4. The same as above but for removing an element
5. Add/Change/Remove an inline style attribute
6. Add event listeners like mousedown/mouseup/mouseover
7. Is faster to add/remove some tags over others? ex: is faster to add/remove a `<div>` or a `<p>`? (In the adding mode: I think is faster `<p>` because it only has 1 letter vs 3 letters, and maybe because div is a container. I don't know, that's why I'm asking :D)

   1. Remove an element, save into js somehow, then re-add it and keep the event listeners working as it were before removing the element

**This a big question, so if you only know some of the questions you can always share what you know ;)**

**thanks thanks!!**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest DOM insertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634878/fastest-dom-insertion)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1   Set the value of `innerHTML` on the parent element to a string containing HTML for the new elements.
2    Same as 1.
4    Set the value of `innerHTML` on the parent element to an empty string.
7.1    Call `Node.removeChild()`, save the returned Node object, and then pass the node to `Node.appendChild()`.

Comment: I have found this link and I'm courious why dom+innerHTML+fragment is faster in ie7,8,9 and dom+fragment is faster in chrome... http://andrew.hedges.name/blog/2008/04/19/innerhtml-versus-the-dom-cant-we-all-just-get-along

Comment: Changing the value of `innerHTML` is overwhelmingly faster than manipulating the DOM when you are inserting a large number of elements into the document.

Comment: then why in those tests is not so? it should be faster, you are right, but the times are not like this..

Comment: did you try replacing the default code so that it inserts a few hundred elements? I did, and it showed that replacing innerHTML was faster (using Firefox 8.0a1)

Comment: of course the one with innerHTML is faster: it only uses innerHTML but the latter uses both innerHTML and DOM

Answer (score 0):

Google/SO are your friends:

For example for question 1/2 , see [Fastest DOM insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634878/how-to-get-fastest-dom-insertion-speed)

I think, you can search for a lot of them.

Another good place to search for performance comparison beside google/SO is to use jsperf: http://jsperf.com/browse and http://jsperf.com/popular. I'm pretty sure there are response to a lot of your question there. And if you have some questions that are unanswered, you can test them as well in the main page http://jsperf.com/.

Comment: All the links are dead.