# Most efficient way to get width of divs inside a container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of text labels and I need to get a width of those labels when rendered inside the browser. So I'm creating a container element on the fly and append a bunch of divs to it.

```
const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.style.display = 'flex';
wrapper.style.position = 'absolute';

text.forEach((t) => {
  const d = document.createElement('div');
  d.textContent = t.headerName;
  wrapper.appendChild(d);
});

document.body.prepend(wrapper);
```

So it's all rendered into a structure like this:

```
ff | other | col2andmore |
```

Now I need to get the width of each element. I do it like this:

```
const data = Array.from(wrapper.childNodes).map((n) => {
  return {
    width: n.offsetWidth,
  }
});
```

**I'm worried about the performance.** I may have tens of thousands of those divs. I know that when reading `offsetWidth` browser has to run styles recomputes. I'm wondering what's the most effecient way to get those numbers from divs? I assume that since the container is `absolute` the recompute will be limited to only this div and its children, not the entire page.

What are your thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: I would think the browser is only going to do the compute once after a dirty change, so as long as you don't dirty the DOM inside your loops, I would expect this to be fast.

Comment: I'd worry more about the performance implications when rendering tens of thousands of divs, not about reading a value that the browser has to compute anyways when rendering the elements.

Comment: you may use `documentFragment` method [have a look on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74910967/update-the-body-of-html-method-using-javascript/74911539#74911539)

Comment: @MisterJojo  Yeah, that's good for adding to the DOM, but the OP needs the DOM here for document flow, `offsetWidth` will not be that useful outside of the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a quick test here, mapping `offsetWidth` inside a loop is very fast.

Below is an example, for me it's about 7ms, the majority of the time is creating the 1000 elements (ps, there are ways to speed that up too).

```js
for (let l = 0; l < 1000; l ++) {
  const s = document.createElement('span');
  s.innerText = `ref:${l} `;
  document.body.appendChild(s);
}

console.time('t1');
const m = [...document.querySelectorAll('span')]
  .map(m => m.offsetWidth);
console.timeEnd('t1');
  
console.log(`size of element 0: ${m[0]}`);
console.log(`size of element 999: ${m[999]}`);
```

[image: Profile for the above]

In the above profile you can see there are 0 reflow's during the `map`.  The next layout calc is about 0.34ms after the `console.timeEnd` and this reflow is only because SO snippets rendering the log.

On the other hand if your dirty the DOM inside the map, you get a massive slowdown.  Quick test 1400ms, IOW: 200 times slower.

And below this is what the profile looks like if you dirty the DOM inside the map,.  See all those purple blocks, are forced reflows, and the red marks are even Chrome warning it's a likely performance bottleneck.

[image: Dirty the DOM in Map]

Comment: thanks for the example, could you maybe check the performance panel to see if the browser has just one or multiple reflows? it's kind of intuitive to think that browser takes a snapshot of sizes and the reads from the snapshot unless there are DOM mutations

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi  Profile shows no layout  /  recalc style or paint during the function call.  So even the first `offsetWidth` didn't cause a reflow calc, I assume because it's already done it anyway and there has been no DOM update from last reflow after adding elements.  IOW: as long as you don't dirty the DOM during the `map` you will have no performance hits due to reflow..

Comment: interesting, could you attach the screenshot? but do you see multiple reflows when changing the DOM?

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi  attached,  can you see were the recalc only happens after `console.timeEnd`,  ps.  Ignore the Timer Fired, placed in a timer to make capturing a bit easier.. :)   I'll do a quick profile of a version that mutates the DOM during map.   eg.  the 200x slower version.

Comment: thanks, so we can say that the way I do it is the most efficient one :)